# How to adjust screen backlight at full disk decryption step

Tags: boot, encryption, brightness, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 11,1 on which I dual-boot Ubuntu 18.04 with full-disk encryption. When prompted to enter my password at the decryption step the screen backlight is turned almost all the way down, so the text is practically unreadable. I did add the following to my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

However this is not executed until after the decryption (makes sense to me).

Is it possible configure the brightness at the decryption prompt through some other configuration file?

Comment: what do you want to read ? the prompt is to type your password , right ? you don't need to see your password ?

Comment: The prompt is preceded by terminal output (I'm not using the splash screen). In either case, even when I used the splash, the same problem persisted: I could barely see what was on the screen. Of course I have an expectation of what should be there and what the boot process requires of me, but I'd like actually be able to read what it says. I'm not looking for additional security through literal obscurity.